# Rails JSON parse unexpected token escapced chars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parsing

I have a string that has been escaped, I want to parse this into JSON but I keep getting errors using rails

```
{\"content\":{\"Soass__text_plain__abc_of_study\":\"Some of Study\",\"Dodeeedd\":
...........
........lots more of the string then comes some \u002d1 etc
```

Parse error on line 160:
...              "id": \u002d1

```
JSON::ParserError: 399: unexpected token at '{"spacer":"http://s.c.xxx.yyyy.com/scds/common/u/img/spacer.gif","i18n_get_discovered_upload":"\u003cstrong\u003eGet discovered\u003c/strong\u003e for your work! Add your videos, images, documents...","bg_promo_1":
```

How can I JSON parse this?

Comment: Try this service to locate bad characters in your JSON: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can build your json with hashes or with arrays, its more simple and clean

```
hash_of_values = {'foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2}
array_of_values = [hash_of_values]
```

And then :

```
JSON.parse(hash_of_values) => "{\"foo\":1,\"bar\":2}"
JSON.parse(array_of_values) => "[{\"foo\":1,\"bar\":2}]"
```

Comment: Its coming from a source as above, I need to get this "unparsed" and what you explained reversed